# How to combine maxima-mode with *imaxima*?

Tags: comint, maxima

How can I setup `emacs` to evaluate maxima code from a buffer in `maxima-mode` in the `*imaxima*` buffer rather than the default `*maxima*` one?

While I can copy and paste the code between buffers, I'm afraid of crashing emacs since my natural use of emacs makes extensive use of frames.

I've tried setting:

```
(setq imaxima-use-maxima-mode-flag t)
```

following [this email thread](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/pipermail/maxima/2009/017685.html) but that only made `(imaxima)` start a normal `*maxima*` repl.

Comment: From looking at Maxima code this doesn't seem to be possible (the name of the buffer holding the output of Maxima's process is hard-coded into the functions dealing with sending contents to the Maxima shell.

Answer (score 3):

*I'm a beginner when it comes to Emacs (Lisp) but the following seems to work (at least for me). I'm also using the Spacemacs configuration framework so there's a possibility of some stuff being Spacemacs-only (feel free to edit such stuff).*

---

For those not yet familiar with imaxima, it's an Emacs package that comes prepackaged with Maxima. To start using it, add the folder in which the scripts reside to your `load-path` and load the necessary files, like this (you may have to adapt the path) (taken from the [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MaximaMode)):

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/local/share/maxima/5.18.1/emacs/")
(autoload 'imaxima "imaxima" "Frontend for maxima with Image support" t)
(autoload 'imath-mode "imath" "Imath mode for math formula input" t)
```

You'll also want to set a few variables since the rendered output is pretty small (at least to me) and because you want imaxima to use the **maxima** buffer:

```
(setq imaxima-use-maxima-mode-flag t)
(setq imaxima-fnt-size "large")
(setq imaxima-pt-size 12)
```

---

From my experimenting and poking around, I conluded that `imaxima-use-maxima-mode-flag` only makes imaxima use the **maxima** buffer instead of its own **imaxima**. That's pretty much it.

Now, if maxima hasn't been started, `imaxima` will start maxima, switch to **maxima** (assuming `imaxima-use-maxima-mode-flag` has been set) and load the appropriate code that is used to render the LaTeX maxima outputs.

**However**, if maxima **has been already been started using `maxima-start` (which is automatically run for you when you call `maxima-display-buffer` and maxima isn't running)**, `imaxima` will do nothing but switch to the **maxima** buffer (again, assuming `imaxima-use-maxima-mode-flag` has been set), i.e. the LaTeX rendering code won't be loaded (unless you loaded it yourself manually or something).

The solution to this is to always run `imaxima` (**with** the `imaxima-use-maxima-mode-flag` set) first and only then run `maxima-display-buffer`. Since the flag is active, `imaxima` will start and load the necessary code inside **maxima** which `maxima-display-buffer` will subsequently switch to and to which other `maxima-*` commands will send expressions to.

For me, `maxima-display-buffer` is bound to `C-c C-p` and I've bound `imaxima` to `C-c C-o` with the following code:

```
(add-hook 'maxima-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (define-key maxima-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-o") 'imaxima)))
```

I tried redefining the original `maxima-display-buffer` to first run `imaxima` and then the original `maxima-display-buffer` but I failed. I'm not really sure how to go about doing that yet so if anyone has any ideas, feel free to comment/edit this answer.

For now, whenever I want to interactively evaluate maxima code I'll first run `imaxima` (using `C-c C-o`) and only after that use the `maxima-*` commands (such as `maxima-display-buffer`, `maxima-send-line`, etc.).